# DisplayTag Jquery Struts2 Ajax Pagination

Tags: jquery, ajax, struts2, displaytag

I have Struts2 working with Jquery + DisplayTag.

Here is the JSP with displayTag:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="sj" uri="/struts-jquery-tags"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="display" uri="http://displaytag.sf.net"%>
<!-- INICIO PAGINACAO -->
<div id="teste">

<display:table id="displayTab" name="ocorrencias" pagesize="20"
    cellpadding="5px;" cellspacing="5px;"
    style="margin-left:50px;margin-top:20px;"
    requestURI="OcorrenciasRecebidos">

    <display:column property="id" title="ID" />
    <display:column property="data" title="DATA RECEBIDO" />
    <display:column property="entidade.nome" title="ENTIDADE RECEBIDO" />
    <display:column property="quantidade" title="OCORRENCIAS" />

</display:table>
</div>
<!--  FIM  PAGINACAO -->
```

The problem: When I click on the number pages of the pagination displaytag, the page refresh's all, not the div id "teste".

How can I make, easily , preference no more plugins, to just refresh the teste div and not the entire page? (I already have struts2 action prepared to just send the table, and not the entire page)